# how do I pass in dynamic data to my child component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm trying to pass in a username and ID into my Support component like this:

```
  <HashRouter>
      <nav>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/profile">My Profile</Link>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/vendor">Vendor Portal</Link>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <Link to="/help">Support</Link>
      </nav>
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} />
        <Route exact path="/profile" element={<AuthComponent />} />
        <Route exact path="/help" element={<Support username={"jim"} id={"weenie"} /> }  />
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
```

and for support:

```
export class Support extends React.Component {
   render() {
    console.log(this.props)
  return (
    <div>
    <div>Support</div>
    <div>
        username?: {this.props.person['username']} <br/>
        User id?: {this.props.person.id}
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}

Support.propTypes = {
  username: PropTypes.string,
  id: PropTypes.string
}
```

I get white screen of death and somehow its called a couple times:

[image]

The props seem to be getting passed in so why is the propTypes breaking on it?

Comment: `this.props.person` and `this.props.id` is enough, see your log statement

Comment: this from  moonwave99 and u should check if the props exists before u try to show it, like do a  if(!this.props.username || !this.props.id )return <div>Loading </div>

Comment: @moonwave99 thank you! I've been focusing so much energy on the Support.propTypes object and fiddling with the router parameters and the parent. OK I'm unblocked now. If you want to expand that into an answer I'll accept and move on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing `username` and `id` as props:

```js
<Support username={"jim"} id={"weenie"} />
```

You can access them directly as `this.props.username` and `this.props.id`.

Also, you can pass strings in JSX directly as `<Support username="jim" id="weenie" />`

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be accessing the "person" property in props, which doesn't exist, and in the "person" you are again trying to read "username", hence the error "reading property username of undefined" because "person" is not there in props.

You will be good to go if you use "this.props.username" and "this.props.id"